# JS fetch of Google Cloud Storage objects gives opaque response

Tags: javascript, http, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to Fetch images stored on Google Cloud Storage from a browser client. However, I'm getting an opaque response. I've generated SignedUrls stored in the data.Prof.Images array which are working when I copy them in the browser and they should give a Body response of a Base64 string. Has anyone come across this how to make Google Cloud Storage send non-opaque responses when Fetching from JS?

```
function fetch_img_params() {
    return {
        method: 'GET',
        mode: 'no-cors',
    };
}

async function GetImages() {
    for (let i=0; i < data.Prof.Images.length; i++) {
        img_res = await fetch(data.Prof.Images[i], fetch_img_params());
        img = await img_res.text();
        document.querySelector("#img" + i).src = img;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Opaque responses occur because of the `no-cors` parameter you set in `fetch_img_params()`.

According to this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch),

> no-cors is intended to make requests to other origins that do not have CORS headers and result in an opaque response

Try using a different [response type](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_types) that will not return an opaque response.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I had to add CORS settings on the Storage bucket so that the server replied with the necessary CORS Headers. Basically I followed this documentation: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/configuring-cors#gsutil_1